# How to find the probability using combinations

Tags: probability, combinations

A maths group consists of $10$ students. $6$ of the students are boys. One of the girls is called Maria, and two of the boys are called Peter and David.
Four students are selected at random

(i) calculate the total number of ways they can be chosen
(ii) how many of these ways include Maria
(iii) how many of these ways include both Peter and David?

For part i, I did $\binom {10} 4 = 210$.
For part ii, I calculated $\binom 9 4$ and then took this away from $210$.

How can I work out part iii?

Answer (score 1):

For part *ii*, you want a group of 4 that contains Maria. Put Maria in the group (there's only 1 way to do that) then pick 3 from the remaining 9. That's ${9}\choose{3}$.

For part *iii* use the same process. Put in Peter and David, then pick 2 from the remaining 8. ${8}\choose{2}$.